# How to make a variables within a constructor call methods?

Tags: java, methods

So I am doing an assignment that is based around the energy consumption within a house. I have created a `Person` constructor that emulates a person within the house. I now want to make that person perform a task which is to have a shower. I have added the task into the Person class and now I need to call it in a `timePasses()` method.

The assignment is about registering the amount of energy consumption used up by applications within a house during a 1 day period. I have created appliances such as `PowerShower`that has a `shower()` method which reads the amount of energy consumption used by that appliance. Now I have been asked to create a `Person` class which has people that us these appliances. So I have created a constructor to store the details of the person and now I want to make that person call the `PowerShower.shower()` method to emulate them using that appliance. I'm having trouble with figuring out how to actually make a person do this task which is what I need help with.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public abstract class Person 
{
    public int personAge;
    public String personName;

    PowerShower callPowerShower = new PowerShower(1,1,1,1);

    Person(int personAge, String personName) 
    {
        this.personAge = personAge;
        this.personName = personName;

    }

    public void addTask()
    {
        callPowerShower.shower();
    }
    public void timePasses()
    {
        //Make Person execute task callPowerShower.shower().
    }
}
```

How would I make a person perform the task? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it's me, but I am having trouble understanding your assignment, your code, and your question, and wonder if your program is even structured correctly. Can you please clarify the assignment, requirements, your code, and your problem?

Comment: I've added a segment in my question which tries to clarify these things.

Comment: why are you calling methods inside the person object. surely you need to initialized a person object and then call your methods on it?

Comment: Where did `Adult` come from? This is getting crazier I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to write adult, it should just be created outside of any method so that it can be used anywhere within the class.

Comment: Moderators flagged for this question as well.

Comment: Why has this question been flagged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming shower takes a Person Object as a parameter?

```
Person bob = new Person(25,"Bob");
PowerShower callPowerShower = new PowerShower(1,1,1,1);
callPowerShower.shower(bob)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want a hierarchy relationship between your your `Adult` class and `Person` class, than ensure that your `Adult` class extends the `Person` class.

Also I would suggest reading a couple of tutorials and books so that you understand Object Oriented Programming in Java.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm